# Azure Event Grid trigger with dynamic @BlobOutput path in JAVA

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

```
@BlobOutput(dataType="Binary", name="$return", path="{data.url}")
```

We are using an Event grid trigger in java to get blob events from blob storage.
Here {data.url} represents an image url with .tiff extension, our function converts the image from .tiff to .png format and saves it back in the same storage.
Is there a way to change {data.url} and set it back to path param of @BlobOutput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowing, for now dynamic binding is only [available for .Net language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#binding-at-runtime), and it creates binding at runtime rather than change declarative binding configuration.

The frank alternative should be using [Storage SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java#microsoft-azure-storage-sdk-v10-for-java) and upload blob to target container manually.

Comment: Yes. For languages other than .net, you cannot modify output binding definitions. This would a feature request. Please open an issue on https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/85